# How to change value in User Property Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

How could I update value in userproperty in Firebase? My code:

```
 FirebaseTracker.setUserPropertyRewardedVideoAds(context, FirebaseRewardedVideoAdsChannel.ADD_BILL);
     FirebaseTracker.setUserPropertyRewardedVideoAds(context, FirebaseRewardedVideoAdsChannel.ADD_BUDGET);
```

but when I open event tap, have no data in user property, event still send.

Comment: Using  DatabaseReference  to set orderByChild firebase query..

Comment: but i want to send event with user properties and i can't change value in my user properties

Comment: Can you turn on the debug mode and look at the events in the console? It should have user properties attached with every event after setting them